# Ruby on rails: breaking down a large test_helper.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, conventions

We have a pretty large `test/test_helper.rb` file, which does quite a few unrelated things. Is there a "Rails way" to decompose it into subfiles, stored in some conventional location?

I tried searching the official docs, but couldn't find anything. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do this in our `spec/spec_helper.rb` (using RSpec rather than Minitest, but the same principle should apply):

```rb
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].sort.each do |file|
  require file
end
```

We then have different configuration files such as `spec/support/vcr.rb`, `spec/support/redis.rb`, etc.

---

edit: This actually came from the file generated by `rspec-rails`. Here is that line as of RSpec 3.9:

```rb
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

Comment: Don't forget about `__dir__` in Ruby 2.4+, or even better, `Rails.root.join('spec/support/...')`

Comment: Ah okay. Just confirming: there's no conventional directory structure that's rails is configured to auto-import, like with controllers and such?

Comment: Ah, looks like this was an auto-generated file from an old version of `rspec-rails` that we never bothered updating...

Comment: @tadman Yep. After you `require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)` at the top of the file, `Rails.root` becomes available for all further `require`s.

Comment: You can also `require_relative '../config/environment'` which is in practice a lot less messy.